# How to show this function is in $L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, haar-measure

$G$ be a locally compact abelian group. $\hat G$ denotes the group of characters on $G$.

$M(G)$ be the space of regular complex Borel measure on $G$.

Now let $\mu \in M(G)$ and $\hat{\mu}\in L^1(\hat G)$.

Define a function $f:G\to \mathbb C$ such that
$$f(x)=\int_{\hat G}{\hat \mu}(\Lambda)\Lambda(x)\mathrm d\Lambda$$
where ${\hat \mu}:\hat G \to \mathbb C $ defined by $$ {\hat \mu}(\Lambda)=\int_G \Lambda(x^{-1})\mathrm d\mu(x) $$ such that $\mathrm dx$ is a haar measure on $G$ and $\mathrm d\Lambda$ is a haar measure on $\hat G$

Clearly the function is well defined at every point as we have $\hat{\mu}\in L^1(\hat G)$.

How do I  show that $f \in L^1(G)$?

I tried taking modulus but didn't help . If $G$ were given compact then it is easy . But for locally compact I have no clue.

Comment: You meant ${\hat \mu}(\Lambda)=\int_G \Lambda(x^{-1})\mathrm d\mu(x)$. Also if $\mu$ is non-negative what does it mean regular Borel ? The Fourier inversion theorem says $d\mu(x)=f(x)dx$ since $f$ is continuous it is $L^1$ iff $\mu(G)<\infty$

Comment: How do I show $ d\mu(x)=f(x)dx $? And I am working with complex measure here .

Comment: Why are you taking a $\mu\in M(G)$ that you never use? Why are you taking an arbitrary $\hat\mu\in L^1(G)$ but then defining $\hat\mu$ to be a specific function (that is ill defined if $G$ is not compact)?